# Homework! ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("filename") never stops reading

Tags: java, serialization

For the record, this is my Java programming assignment. It's a simple output some data to a file and read it back in type assignment. I've already done in previous classes simple writing to text files so I wanted to make this one more difficult. In my book there is a topic about using `ObjectOutputStream(new FileInputStream);` and `ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream)` to read and write complete objects. Now, I'm sure that I'm writing 2 objects to this file, the first few tests I only wrote one and then saw the byte size double when I wrote 2. Both objects are of the same type. When I try to read them back in the program gets stuck on the first object in the file and never moves to the next and never throws `EOFException` to show the end of the file. Now I'm stumped. I've checked and rechecked the example in my book and searched online and I can't figure why I can't read back in these objects. I've still got plenty of time to complete this assignment so I'm not worried about getting it in on time.

```
 import java.io.EOFException;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
 import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;


 public class TextFileIO {
     static int[] evenNumbers = new int[50];
     static int[] oddNumbers = new int[50];
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int evenCount = 0;
    int oddCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            evenNumbers[evenCount] = i;
            evenCount++;
        }
        else{
            oddNumbers[oddCount] = i;
            oddCount++;
        }
    }
    ArraySerializable even = new ArraySerializable(evenNumbers);
    ArraySerializable odd = new ArraySerializable(oddNumbers);

    writeToFile(even, odd);


    readFile();
}

public static void writeToFile(ArraySerializable array, ArraySerializable array2){
    try {
          ObjectOutputStream    output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("numbers.dat"));
          output.writeObject(array);
          output.writeObject(array2);
          output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void readFile(){

        ObjectInputStream input = null;
        try{
            while(true){
                input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("numbers.dat"));
                ArraySerializable array;
                array = (ArraySerializable) input.readObject();
                int[] numbers = array.getNumbers();
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                    System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ,");
                }
        }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException |  ClassNotFoundException |EOFException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

}

and my ArraySerializable class:

```
 import java.io.Serializable;


 public class ArraySerializable implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int[] numbers;

public ArraySerializable(int[] numbers){
    this.numbers = numbers;
}

public int[] getNumbers(){
    return numbers;
}
```

}

Comment: `while(true)`? How should that stop without running into an exception if you don't have a `break` or `return` anythere in that loop? Also you're missing a curly bracket in that code. (The bracket that closes this while loop). Also look what a finally block is and how it may help you here.

Comment: From what I can tell, the book says that the program should throw `EOFExecption`, where int he catch for that I have `return;` What I read online, this is the only reliable way to tell if you read in all objects in the file.

Comment: You could also loop until the read object becames null. This could/should also indicates the end of the file. Waiting for the exception to get triggered is not a good code behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> never stops reading

*You* never stop reading. You open the file, read one object, close the file, open the file, ...

Get rid of the 'while (true)'.

If your intention was to read multiple objects from the same file, restructure your loop to do that. Specifically, move the open and close outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I see now I was opening and closing the file in the loop, reading only the first object. I moved the input variable as a property of the class and it worked! `While(true)` actually works, it runs until `EOFException` is hit, where it is returned to the calling method. Is there a better way? I was doubting this from the book myself...

Comment: That's the right way. You'll read all sorts of nonsense from exception-phobic thought police about this, but the fact is that this API throws EOFException at end of stream: therefore you have to catch it.